# If $a_1<a_2<a_3$ then prove that $a_2+a_3 > 2a_1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I use this approach

$a_3>a_1$, then let $a_3 = ka_1$, where $k > 1$.

$a_2>a_1$, then let $a_2 = ma_1$, where $m > 1$.

Then $ka_1+ma_1 > 2a_1 \implies k+m>2$

also $k>1$
and  $m>1$
so $k+m>2$ prooved.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 6):

Your proof is actually technically incorrect. In particular, when you write

> Then $ka_1+ma_1 > 2a_1 \implies k+m>2$

is incorrect. The direction of your implication is incorrect. The implication should be "we know X, therefore, we know Y". And in your proof, you should say:

- We know that $k, m>1$, therefore, we know that $m+n>1+1=2$.
- Therefore, we know that $(m+n)a_1 > 2a_1$.

So the implication goes $$m+n > 2 \implies (m+n)a_1 > 2a_1$$

but even with this correction, the above implication is only valid for **positive** values of $a_1,a_2,a_3$! The inequality you are trying to prove actually holds for **all** values $a_1, a_2, a_3$. The problem is that $k$ in your proof is only greater than $1$ in the particular case when all values are positive.

In fact, all problems above stem from one single source:

***You are overcomplicating things.***

Below is a much simpler proof:

$$a_2 + a_3 > a_1 + a_3 > a_1 + a_1 = 2a_1$$

The first inequality follows from the fact that $a_2>a_1$. The second inequality follows from the fact that $a_3 > a_1$. Also, both inequalities use the fact that if $a>b$, then for any $c$, we have $a+c>b+c$.